# Sorting array of struct in Julia

Tags: sorting, struct, julia

Suppose if I have the following in Julia:

```
mutable struct emptys
    begin_time::Dict{Float64,Float64}; finish_time::Dict{Float64,Float64}; Revenue::Float64
end
population = [emptys(Dict(),Dict(),-Inf) for i in 1:n_pop] #n_pop is a large positive integer value.
for ind in 1:n_pop
    r = rand()
    append!(population[ind].Revenue, r)
    append!(population[ind].begin_time, Dict(r=>cld(r^2,rand())))
    append!(population[ind].finish_time, Dict(r=>r^3/rand()))
 end
```

Now I want to sort this population based on the Revenue value. Is there any way for Julia to achieve this? If I were to do it in Python it would be something like this:

```
sorted(population, key = lambda x: x.Revenue) # The population in Python can be prepared using https://pypi.org/project/ypstruct/ library.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a whole range of [sorting functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/sort/) in Julia.  The key functions are `sort` (corresponding to Python's `sorted`) and `sort!` (corresponding to Python's `list.sort`).

And as in Python, they have a [couple of keyword arguments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/sort/#Base.sort!), one of which is `by`, corresponding to `key`.

Hence the translation of

```py
sorted(population, key = lambda x: x.Revenue)
```

would be

```
getrevenue(e::emptys) = e.Revenue
sort(population, by=getrevenue)
```

Or `e -> e.Revenue`, but having a getter function is good style anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day.